# Magento categoty import

Tags: php, magento

My client want a batch process from cli, every night he delete category from magento server. He has its own system from where he export list of category everyday, i have all data to import category except one, ids. The export file contain static sql id ,

if i import this into magento i get new ids, then i have manually assign sub-category and product, i loose client cart info...

My question is is there any way i can assign static id to category , sub-category and product. so if i delete & update system they always behave the same..?

is magmi or any other tool can solve this issue..?

Answer (score 0):

the [Magmi category importer/creator](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer) plugin can find/create/assign product categories by category tree named definition (like level1/level2/level3) using the "categories" column in CSV.
This is the most reliable way to not have to use category ids & to retrieve existing product category assignment or create new ones from one import to another.

Comment: Well thank for reply, how about this issue. 
I have category -> products associated with it, now I delete category and re-import list from file. 
Do products will auto associate with it?

Comment: indeed, magmi does that automatically